# K means clustering on text data in R

Tags: r, k-means

I have a book.csv file containing 30 instances. There are 3 attribute columns: Title, Author, BookSummary.

Sample is shown below :

```
Title, Author, BookSummary

The Da Vinci Code, Dan Brown, Louvre curator and Priory of Sion Grand Master Jacques Saunière is fatally shot one night at the museum by an albino Catholic monk named Silas, who is working on behalf of someone known only as the Teacher, who wishes to discover the location of the "keystone," an item crucial to the search for the Holy Grail.<br>
```

In this sample I am just showing 1st instance.There are 30 rows like this in data.
I am performing K-Means on this data set in R tool. I performed following commands:-

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/Experiment/book.csv")
corpus.tmp<-Corpus(VectorSource(data))
View(corpus)

corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp,removePunctuation)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, stripWhitespace)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, tolower)
corpus.tmp<- tm_map(corpus.tmp, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
TDM <- TermDocumentMatrix(corpus.tmp)
inspect(TDM)

tdm_tfxidf<-weightTfIdf(TDM)

m<- as.matrix(tdm_tfxidf)
rownames(m)<- 1:nrow(m)

norm_eucl<- function(m)
  m/apply(m,1,function(x) sum(x^2)^.5)

m_norm<-norm_eucl(m)

results<-kmeans(m_norm,5,5)
```

This code is clustering the number of terms that are formed using `DocumentTermMatrix()`. But, I want to cluster on the basis of instances rather than on the basis of terms.

Please tell me how to do this.

Comment: how do I combine terms belonging to particular instance. So that I can cluster instances?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your data is not in the expected format. I guess if you transpose you data prior to kmeans() it should be fine.